# Quarkus: execute parallel unis

Tags: kotlin, reactive-programming, quarkus, mutiny

In a quarkus / kotlin application, I want to start multiple database requests concurrently. I am new at quarkys and I am not sure if I am doing things right:

```
    val uni1 = Uni.createFrom().item(repo1).onItem().apply { it.request() }
    val uni2 = Uni.createFrom().item(repo2).onItem().apply { it.request() }

    return Uni.combine().all()
      .unis(uni1, uni2)
      .asTuple()
      .onItem()
      .apply { tuple ->
        Result(tuple.item1, tuple.item2) }
      .await()
      .indefinitely()
```

Will the `request()` really be made in parallel? Is it the right way to do it in quarkus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code is right.

`Uni.combine().all()` runs all the passed Unis concurrently. You will get the tuple (containing the individual results) when all the Unis have completed (emitted a result).

From your code, you may remove the tuple step and use `combineWith` instead.

Finally, note that the `await().indefinitely()` blocks the caller thread, forever if one of the Uni does not complete (for whatever reason). I strongly recommend using `await().atMost(...)`

Comment: Have you tested this? In my experience `Uni` still executes everything in one thread. It returns immediately, but the actual execution is in series.

Comment: Depends on how the requests are executed, but yes it runs them concurrently. See https://gist.github.com/cescoffier/1ed68bef12b798529e10350f77686e9a as an example.

If request() are synchronous then yes, of course, it won't work, they need to be asynchronous to be run concurrently.